# SQL - find distances between two cities, have to format the table

Tags: sql, hive

I am a beginner to SQL and have a question that involves running a query in Hive which I think is very similar / the same as SQL code. My data table looks as follows:

```
name     lat     long
NY       40.3    70.3
SF       36.1    60.2
LA       36.5    53.1
CH       45.2    62.3
...
```

i need to find all cities within a certain distance from one another, with distance being measured by latitutde and longitude.

My current idea on how to solve this is as follows:

1. If there are n=10 cities (thus n=10 rows in the table), create a new table with (10*9)/2 = 45 rows, where each row now has 6 columns (city1, city2, lat1, lat2, long1, long2)
2. With rows in this format, I can simply use a pythagorean like calculation to calculate the distance.

I'm not sure how to do step 1 in SQL. Essentially its creating every possible unique combination of pairs from the first column, and including the corresponding lat and long for each city in the pair in that row.

Is this approach smart? and how could i implement it? is there a better way?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this task with a `self-join`.

```
select 
d1.name as city1, d2.name as city2,
d1.lat as lat1, d2.lat as lat2, 
d1.long as long1, d2.long as long2
from datatable d1
join datatable d2 on d1.name < d2.name
```

Edit: As Hive doesn't support inequality joins in versions below 2.2.0, you can use

```
select 
d1.name as city1, d2.name as city2,
d1.lat as lat1, d2.lat as lat2, 
d1.long as long1, d2.long as long2
from datatable d1
join datatable d2 on 1=1
where d1.name < d2.name
```

Comment: your variables are confusing me a small bit. shouldn't d1.city and d2.city be d1.name and d2.name? and d1 and d2 are the same table in my database, but we are assigning different names to them somehow?

Comment: ya sorry for the typo..i edited it now..yes they are the same table but we give them different column-aliases.

Comment: is datatable a keyword, or is that the name of my table? - yeah this was a dumb question. i wasn't aware that we could use two versions of the table like this with d1 and d2, thanks

Comment: it's the name of your table.

Comment: the last line with the join is tossing an error -  "Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'name'"

Comment: should we be using d1.city1 and d2.city2 instead of d1.name and d2.name in the last row?

Comment: Only equality joins, outer joins, and left semi joins are supported in Hive. Hive does not support join conditions that are not equality conditions as it is very difficult to express such conditions as a map/reduce job.

Comment: @vp_arth ..  complex conditions including inequalities in joins is supported from versions 2.2.0+ .. check this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins#LanguageManualJoins-MapJoinRestrictions

Comment: @Canovice .. as vp_arth points out, inequality joins aren't supported in hive if you are using a version below 2.2.0 .